# Printing the data type of a temporary variable and displaying it in either the Results or Messages tab

Tags: sql, t-sql, type-conversion, sql-server-2019

In Python, if I convert a variable, I can check that the variable is the intended data type via a try-catch block, or just print to the console after the conversion takes place.

How can I do something similar in SQL server 2019?

```
declare
@Rep_Date VARCHAR(64) = '2023-11-02';
```

Below is implicit conversion. Is there a better explicit conversion available to use?
If so, how would I do this?

```
declare
@Per_Date DATETIME = @Rep_Date;
```

There's code "below" this that never uses @Rep_Date only uses @Per_Date

How can I verify/be check that @Per_Date is a DATETIME temp variable and not VARCHAR(64)?
*/

To print the data type to "console" I have tried:

```
print(type(@Per_Date))
print(type(select @Per_Date))
```

To explicitly convert I have tried:

I have only used CAST or CONVERT in a select statement but never directly on a single temp variable.

Comment: Your question currently asks multiple things (which isn't allowed); one of the things your question is asking is an opinion-based thing (which isn't allowed). Please edit your question to ask only one thing, and ensure that it is an objectively answerable thing. Requests for how to do something "better" are open-ended and opinion-based, and thus off-topic here.

Comment: Could you explain what you need this for? Generally, you should know the type of the variable already

Answer (score 2):

If you want explicit conversion then you would use [`CONVERT` or `CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or, if you want to avoid conversion errors, `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST` (which will return `NULL` instead when the conversion fails).

As for getting the data type you could (ab)use the `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY` function. If you pass the variable to it as the first parameter, it will be implicitly converted to a `sql_variant` of the base type of the variable, and then you can request to base type from the function:

```sql
DECLARE @Rep_Date varchar(64) = '2023-11-02', 
        @Act_Date date;
SET @Act_Date = CONVERT(date,@Rep_Date,120); --Style 120 is yyyy-MM-dd
SELECT @Rep_Date AS Rep_Date,
       @Act_Date AS Act_Date,
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@Rep_Date,N'BaseType') AS Rep_Date_Type,
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@Act_Date,N'BaseType') AS Act_Date_Type;
```

As you'll note, however, this doesn't tell you what the length/precision/scale/Bytes of that data type is. You would need to use `'MaxLength'`/`'Precision'`/`'Scale'`/`'Bytes'` to get that.

Comment: Another option: `select * from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('DECLARE @Rep_Date varchar(64) = ''2023-11-02'', @Act_Date date; SET @Act_Date = CONVERT(date,@Rep_Date,120); SELECT @Rep_Date, @Act_Date;', NULL, 0)`

Comment: I thought of that one, @Charlieface , but I was less a "fan" as it involved a deferred statement with the entire statement as a literal.

Answer (score 1):

You do this with Python because it is dynamically typed.

SQL is not dynamically typed. In SQL, a variable is and always will be **exactly** the type you declare it to be. If an implicit conversion fails with an assignment, the code immediately throws an error.

This means there is no possible way for the code in the question to end up with `@Per_Date` as a `VARCHAR(64)`. It can't happen.

The one thing you might want is [`TRY_CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or [`TRY_CAST()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), which allow you to attempt a conversion without throwing an error.